# at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" on heroku.How i can deploy truely?How i fix the problem ? thanks everybody

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack

2021-02-04T21:14:34.888815+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
2021-02-04T21:14:34.888815+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
2021-02-04T21:14:34.888815+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
2021-02-04T21:14:34.888816+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
2021-02-04T21:14:34.888816+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) {
2021-02-04T21:14:34.888816+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-02-04T21:14:34.888817+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/server.js' ]
2021-02-04T21:14:34.888817+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-02-04T21:14:34.939405+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-04T21:14:34.986938+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-04T21:15:03.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user
2021-02-04T21:20:20.449954+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 21abf2c8 by user
2021-02-04T21:20:20.449954+00:00 app[api]: Release v7 created by user
2021-02-04T21:20:21.611307+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-02-04T21:20:27.675645+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295117+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:928
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295138+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295138+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295138+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295139+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295139+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295139+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295140+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:15)
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295141+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295141+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295141+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295142+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object. (/app/server.js:3:17)
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295142+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295142+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)2021-02-04T21:20:30.295143+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295143+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295143+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12) {
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295143+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295144+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/server.js' ]
2021-02-04T21:20:30.295144+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-02-04T21:20:30.345918+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-04T21:20:30.384592+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-04T21:20:34.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-02-04T21:21:02.683135+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ibeggg.herokuapp.com request_id=d281c400-d1b2-43fd-810b-b5d050ea7e11 fwd="88.229.116.225" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-04T21:21:02.994155+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ibeggg.herokuapp.com request_id=3a6125c6-23f7-4c18-8de7-f00a7bd86abb fwd="88.229.116.225" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-04T21:28:25.252658+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `printenv` by user
2021-02-04T21:28:31.185921+00:00 heroku[run.7047]: Awaiting client
2021-02-04T21:28:31.198973+00:00 heroku[run.7047]: State changed from starting to up
2021-02-04T21:28:31.470030+00:00 heroku[run.7047]: Starting process with command `printenv`
2021-02-04T21:28:35.582815+00:00 heroku[run.7047]: Process exited with status 0
2021-02-04T21:28:35.613815+00:00 heroku[run.7047]: State changed from up to complete
2021-02-04T21:37:37.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user
2021-02-04T21:42:37.645366+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 33855d7b by user
2021-02-04T21:42:37.645366+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user
2021-02-04T21:42:39.338912+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-02-04T21:42:46.215776+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281568+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:928
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281609+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281610+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281610+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281611+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281611+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281616+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281620+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:15)
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281625+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281633+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281634+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281634+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object. (/app/server.js:2:17)
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281634+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281635+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)2021-02-04T21:42:48.281635+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281635+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281636+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12) {
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281636+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281636+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/server.js' ]
2021-02-04T21:42:48.281636+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-02-04T21:42:48.381857+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-04T21:42:48.421596+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-04T21:42:48.424452+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-02-04T21:42:50.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-02-04T21:42:53.416520+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764452+00:00 app[web.1]: node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:928
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764468+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764469+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764470+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764470+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'express'
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764470+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764471+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/server.js
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764472+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:15)
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764472+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764473+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764473+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764474+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object. (/app/server.js:2:17)
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764474+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764474+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)2021-02-04T21:42:54.764475+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764475+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764475+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12) {
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764476+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764476+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [ '/app/server.js' ]
2021-02-04T21:42:54.764476+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-02-04T21:42:54.783537+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-02-04T21:42:54.805161+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-02-04T21:43:39.306196+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=ibeggg.herokuapp.com request_id=6c4f76c5-ce13-407f-849f-50c996a70f84 fwd="88.229.116.225" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-02-04T21:43:39.952043+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=ibeggg.herokuapp.com request_id=b46ee43b-b1c4-4d70-8172-e983ebbe7784 fwd="88.229.116.225" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

```
My package.json:
{
  "name": "chat-web-sdk-react-sample",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Zopim Web SDK Sample App (React)",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist/*",
    "copy": "copyfiles -f ./src/index.html ./dist",
    "dist": "npm run copy & webpack --env=dist",
    "lint": "eslint ./src",
    "posttest": "npm run lint",
    "serve": "node server.js --env=dev",
    "serve:dist": "node server.js --env=dist",
    "start": "node server.js --env=dev",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Zendesk",
  "engineStrict": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=4.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.1.14",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.1.14",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.1.14",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.1.14",
    "@zendeskgarden/tailwindcss": "^1.1.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.11.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.0.15",
    "bower-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.9",
    "copyfiles": "^0.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "eslint": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "glob": "^7.0.0",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "postcss": "^5.0.11",
    "postcss-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.0.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.2.9",
    "rimraf": "^2.4.3",
    "sass-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack": "^1.12.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.6.0",
    "@zendeskgarden/container-modal": "^0.8.5",
    "@zendeskgarden/container-schedule": "^1.3.7",
    "@zendeskgarden/css-variables": "^6.4.5",
    "@zendeskgarden/react-accordions": "^8.30.0",
    "@zendeskgarden/react-theming": "^8.30.0",
    "@zendeskgarden/svg-icons": "^6.27.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "collections": "^2.0.3",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "graphql": "^15.4.0",
    "lodash": "^4.15.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^15.7.0",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.5.2",
    "store": "^1.3.20",
    "storybook-host": "^5.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.2.0",
    "websocket": "^1.0.33",
    "wss": "^3.3.4"
  },
  "license": "ISC"
}

my server.js :
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
const config = require('./webpack.config');
const app = express();
const open = require('open');
const ip_address = '127.0.0.1';
const PORT = process.env.PORT;

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), config.devServer)
.listen(process.env.PORT , ip_address, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(__dirname);
//=> '/Users/sindresorhus/rainbow'
 
console.log(process.cwd());
//=> '/Users/sindresorhus/unicorn'

//=> '/Users/sindresorhus/unicorn/foo.js'
  console.log(`Listening at ${ip_address}:${process.env.PORT}`);
  console.log('Opening your system browser...');
  open(`http://${ip_address}:${process.env.PORT}/webpack-dev-server/`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`express` is missing from your `package.json`. Additionally, `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server` are `devDependencies`, which Heroku probably doesn't install.

Run

```
npm i --save express webpack webpack-dev-server
```

then commit and push your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` and redeploy.

If `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server` are not under `dependencies` but `devDependencies` in `package.json` after running that, run `npm uninstall webpack webpack-dev-server` and then run the command again.

Comment: Thansk for helping .I have to delete some .bin files for unistall and install this. Im getting this 
TypeError: webpack.NoErrorsPlugin is not a constructor.